# Measure performance in kettlebell?

Tags: running, calories, calculation, kettlebell, measurements

How can I measure my performance and how many calories I burn during swings, high pulls, etc, when exercising with kettlebells? I want to measure how effective I was during training.

I am also running and my training app measures calories , so I could get a clear view how efficient are kettlebells vs running.

Comment: Related to: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/14961/metabolic-equations-for-anaroebic-exercise

Comment: See also: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/12435/is-it-possible-to-measure-calorie-burn-from-heart-rate-alone?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply obtain a heart rate monitor and estimate the relative VO2 figures per: [Is it possible to measure calorie burn from heart rate alone?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/12435/is-it-possible-to-measure-calorie-burn-from-heart-rate-alone?rq=1), and from the VO2 figure the calories.