# How to calculate calories burned while running

Tags: running, calories

I am developing an app for running and I can't find precise formulas for calories burned while running. I need a various formulas based on gender, age, height, weight, distance, time and so on. Any accurate formulas would be a great help for me.

Comment: related: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/3808/how-accurate-are-the-calorie-counters-on-iphone-apps/3822#3822

Answer (score 1):

There aren't any **accurate** equations, without data from an ECG and face mask based gas analyzers.

The best you can do without a true heart rate and O2 measures is to estimate a [VO2max](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VO2_max) figure, and convert that into a Kcal one:

**Kcal/Min ~= 5 calories * massKg * VO2 / 1000**

The [ACMS Running VO2max](http://blue.utb.edu/mbailey/handouts/pdf/MetCalnew.pdf) equation will give a number that's accurate within: +/-14.5% and the conversion to Kcal will multiply the error by a bit.

**VO2 = 0.2 (speed) + 0.9 (speed)(fractional grade) + 3.5**

Comment: In addition, there are numerous charts around on the internet for running varied by pace and weight. Take the average of a bunch of them and call it good.