# Is there a table of effort needed when running uphill and downhill?

Tags: running, long-distance-running, running-training-plan, effort

I'm training by running on trails. There is a lot of uphill and downhill sections in my routes, so I would like to split a route in sections which have similar slope then calculate a pace for every section of the route.

I would like to know if there some kind of factor or a table of effort that could help me to calculate this.

Comment: If it exists, you would still have to provide the angles of incline/decline. Could you do that?

Comment: Yes, with a gps route you have latitude, longitude and elevation for every point, then I'm calculating sections between 2 points and with that I have the incline/decline angles.

Comment: See: [How to calculate calories burned while running](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/24553/how-to-calculate-calories-burned-while-running/24557)

Comment: But your body is the best measure of your effort.  Why not just target a constant heart rate?

Comment: related: [Calculate burned calories (Running) without heart rate](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/25176/calculate-burned-calories-running-without-heart-rate)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The page Teemu found links to http://jap.physiology.org/content/93/3/1039. Here is what I get by eyeballing *Figure 1, Metabolic energy cost of walking or running as a function of the gradient*, figure B:

Grade........ Energy used compared to flat
-50%..........105%
-40%..........100%
-30%...........70%
-20%...........60%
-10%...........60%
0%............100%
10%...........170%
20%...........250%
30%...........360%
40%...........420%
50%...........550%

Comment: yes this is a very good candidate of answer to the question!

Comment: Thanks for the encouragement! It got me to pull out the data into a more quickly useful answer.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look of a "Constant Effort" table of [Calories burned running and walking](http://fellrnr.com/wiki/Calories_burned_running_and_walking) page at [FellRnr.com](http://fellrnr.com). That site is a treasure trove of all kind of running related data

Comment: Just for clarification: Fellrnr is quoting the same paper by Minelli as Noumenon does in his answer. So they are based on the same data/formulas (but there are a lot of other formulas around ...).