# Burned calories formula with conversation factor

Tags: calories, calculation

I've found topic about burned calories formula which is available [here](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/25472/how-to-calculate-calorie-from-pedometer). But as a I am looking at it, some lines are not as clear understandable for me as I expected.

As you can see, there are some conversation factor that I truly don't know what is for.

Why does he use calculation for burned calories per kilometer and then count steps per mile? Thanks.

[image: text]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably a typo. If you look at what they're trying to achieve, it becomes quite obvious.

> conversationFactor = CaloriesPerKilometer / stepCountMile;

This is clearly trying to get a factor (As per the name, good job captain obvious!)

The next step is to figure out how many calories are burned.

> CaloriesBurned = numSteps * conversationFactor;

This is **Converting**, not **Conversing**, the number of steps into Calories. Which means it is either a typo, or someone who's not well versed in English that wrong the code.

Comment: But how is it possible to divide caloriesPerKilometer and number of steps? Is there any calculation hidden behind that?

Comment: Or is it better to ask, why is it needed to divide by miles? Can I use stepCountKilometer instead?

Comment: It seems to be converting every metric measurements into imperial to deal with in Miles. (userWeight * 2.2, converts kg to lbs, userHeight * 0.415 I assume converts cm to inches, but this one is off by quite a lot)

Comment: 0.415 is average size of adult mans foot. but 160934.4 is convertion for cm in one mile. Does that change anything?

Comment: I have no idea how this formula works or the science behind it. I was merely reverse engineering the values.

Comment: I will try to describe it somehow in my bachelor thesis with your suggestions. Thank you for replies.